# How do I force the wordpress to remove the slush and show 404 page?

Tags: wordpress

I transferred thousands of posts from Blogger to WordPress
In order not to lose archiving, I modified the 404.php page so that it shows the posts content with same old slug saved in post meta  of the article, and adding `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");`.

The problem is that at first the old links were working fine, but when I pressed the click Save changes button on the `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` page, my idea no longer worked.
And any old link became like:

`https://exemple.com/2023/10/blog-post_779.html`

Redirect to
 `https://exemple.com/2023/10/blog-post_779.html/`

Knowing that I use `/%postname%` Permalink structure, and i don't have any redirect functions in my theme or htaccess.

How do I force the site to remove the slush and show 404 page?